# Erro ao criar banco de dados com Hibernate e Spring MVC

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring

Estou com um problema executar a aplicação.

Erro...

```
    ERROR [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'categoriaController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'categoriaDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'categoriaDao' is expected to be of type 'sistema.estoque.springmvc.dao.CategoriaDao' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:540)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:171)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:250)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:546)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:517)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:559)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:101)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'categoriaDao' is expected to be of type 'sistema.estoque.springmvc.dao.CategoriaDao' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:378)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 41 more

14:09:19,146 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Estoque04: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Estoque04: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'categoriaController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'categoriaDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'categoriaDao' is expected to be of type 'sistema.estoque.springmvc.dao.CategoriaDao' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86'
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'categoriaController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'categoriaDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'categoriaDao' is expected to be of type 'sistema.estoque.springmvc.dao.CategoriaDao' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:540)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:171)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:250)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:546)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:517)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:559)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:101)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'categoriaDao' is expected to be of type 'sistema.estoque.springmvc.dao.CategoriaDao' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:378)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 41 more

14:09:19,155 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "Estoque04-1.0.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Estoque04" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Estoque04: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'categoriaController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'categoriaDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'categoriaDao' is expected to be of type 'sistema.estoque.springmvc.dao.CategoriaDao' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86'
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'categoriaController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'categoriaDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'categoriaDao' is expected to be of type 'sistema.estoque.springmvc.dao.CategoriaDao' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86'
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'categoriaDao' is expected to be of type 'sistema.estoque.springmvc.dao.CategoriaDao' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86'"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Estoque04"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
```

```java
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JPAConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter );

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("123123");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/sistema-web-05");
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        emf.setJpaProperties(properties);
        emf.setPackagesToScan("sistema.estoque.springmvc.model");
        return emf;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
    }
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/categoria")
public class CategoriaController {

    @Autowired
    private CategoriaDao categoriaDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String form() {
        return "/categoria/formulario";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "categorias", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView categorias() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("categoria/categorias");
        try {
            modelAndView.addObject("categorias", categoriaDao.find());
            System.out.println(categoriaDao.find());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return modelAndView;
    }

    public void salvar() {

    }

}

@Repository
@Transactional
public class CategoriaDao implements DAO<Categoria>, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "BD")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void add(Categoria entity) {
        try {
            em.persist(entity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Categoria entity) {
        try {
            em.merge(entity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Categoria entity) {
        try {
            Categoria categoria = em.merge(entity);
            em.remove(categoria);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Categoria> find() {
        return em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Categoria c").getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public Categoria findById(int id) {
        try {
            return em.find(Categoria.class, id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean isExiste(int id) {
        Categoria categoria = findById(id);
        if (categoria != null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Categoria> findByName(String name) {
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Categoria c WHERE c.nome LIKE :nome");
        query.setParameter("nome", "%" + name + "%");
        return query.getResultList();
    }

}
```

Comment: coloquei @BrunoCésar.

Comment: Coloque a classe `CategoriaDao` e a classe onde você a injeta, por favor.

Comment: É possível que no _controller_ você esteja tentando fazer o _autowiring_ da implementação concreta do DAO, não na interface. Inclua o trecho do _controller_ que fica mais fácil de ajudar. Então, ou você ajusta este _autowiring_, ou habilita o _proxy_ CGLIB

Comment: É isso mesmo @BrunoCésar. Como faço para resolver? O autowiring tem que ser injetado em uma interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu `CategoriaController`, você deve mudar esse trecho:

```
@Autowired
private CategoriaDao categoriaDao;
```

Para:

```
@Autowired
private DAO<Categoria> categoriaDao;
```

Sempre que você for injetar um componente, refira-se a ele pela interface.